# OS X pip doesn't search .pypirc when installing packages?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pypi

So I created a file ~/.pypirc

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    custom

[custom]
repository: https://dist.secretrepo.com/simple/
username: user
password: 12345
```

And added in my requirements.txt a version of a package that was only available on my custom pypi instance. However, no matter what I try, it won't pick it up? The same setup works fine on a linux box, just not on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: are you adding the index flag to the pip call?
eg. `pip install my-package -i custom`
What sort of messages do you get back?

Answer (score 4):

No, `pip` doesn't use `.pypirc` *at all*. `.pypirc` is only used by tools that publish packages to an index, and `pip` doesn't publish packages.

You need to create a [`pip.conf` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration), and add a global `index-url` entry:

```
[global]
index-url = https://user:12345@dist.secretrepo.com/simple/
```

Note that the username and password are included in the URL.

You can also include the `--index-url` option [in your `requirements.txt` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format).